# How to set default facebook share text with application?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

im trying to set default text/message via facebook share/dialog button. First of all, i know that share button has been deprecated, so i cant use that. Second, i have been trying to use whatever methods suggested on the net, but neither one of them works for me.

[image]

So here i am. Even when i try to use the application id, it also failed.

[image]

Please help.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a Facebook app - there you will assign a URL for your app to live, this is the redirect_uri. If you URL is different than the one you're sharing from you will get error code 191.

Comment: im developing thisfor my chrome extension. So basically, this extension is the override homepage for chrome thus it does not have any url or whatever. How does i solve this exactly? is it possible?